# Здравствуйте! получил данные c сервера, не могу получить ключи: id,first_name,last_name и т.д. Вывести названия всех ключей в объекте пользователя

Tags: javascript

```
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?per_page=12')
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  return response.json();
}).then((body) => {
    console.log('-----------')
    console.log('Пункт №1:')
    console.log('-----------')
    console.log(body.data);

    console.log('-----------')
    console.log('Пункт №2:')
    console.log('-----------')
    body.data.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.last_name)
    });
    body.data.filter(item => item.last_name.startsWith('F'))
        .forEach(element => {
            console.log(element.last_name);
    });
    
    console.log(body.data.reduce((acc, item)=>acc + item.first_name + " 
    " + item.last_name +', ', "Наша база содержит данные следующих 
    пользователей:"));

    // Object.entries(body.data).forEach(([key]) => {
    //     console.log(key)
    // })

    Object.keys(body.data).forEach(element=>
                console.log(element)
            );
});
```

Comment: Области видимости.

Comment: Я только учусь, пытаюсь разобраться в коде. Что не так с  Object.keys,почему не могу получить все ключи?????

Comment: `Object.values(body.data).forEach(user => ...)` body.data - массив объектов с ключами. Ключи здесь - индексы. Поэтому можно просто `body.data.forEach(user => ...)`.

Comment: выдает ключи со значениями, а не чисто ключи
{id: 11, email: 'george.edwards@reqres.in', first_name: 'George',

Comment: как получит ключи Id, email без значения?